# How to remove property from json object ignoring casing

Tags: c#

i have json object which will be same in all cases and i have list of string it may vary in combination of casing.
all i want is for every string in list remove property from Json object ignoring caseing.

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using Newtonsoft.Json;
       using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
       using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
                
       public class Program
       {
         public static void Main()
         {
           List<string> list= new List<string>();
           list.Add("_iD");//this can be _ID or _Id any casing combination
           list.Add("_NewId");//same as above
    
           JObject abc = new JObject(
                 new JProperty("_id", "100047"), 
                 new JProperty("_newId", "100048"));//no change in object
    
           foreach(string s in list){
               abc.Remove(s); //this code doesn't ignore casing. please suggest.
         }
        }
      }
```

expected o/p: JObject abc should be empty.
as string doesnot match in casing it doesn't remove any property from above json object.

Comment: You would probably have to query for the token by name converted to all upper or lower, then remove it with the returned reference. However, you say the json is always the same - why not write a class that matches the json structure and deserialize it? Any properties not in your class will be ignored from the json.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
foreach(var p in abc.Properties.Where(p => list.Contains(p.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList())
{
    abc.Remove(p.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to query first and there are a lot of options here, simplest and closer to what you have already of what I can think right now is following:

```cs
foreach (string s in list)
{
    var property = abc.Property(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    if (property != null)
    {
        abc.Remove(property.Name);
    }
}
```